# Wordpress translating urls of pages

Tags: wordpress, url, plugins, multilingual

i am trying to build a multilanguage website in wordpress. I made everthing working but one thing. When i have a page in different languages they all get the same url of the main language. But i want for example if i am on nl.foo.com
that the url looks like this:

```
nl.foo.com/hallo-wereld/
```

and if i am on en.foo.com i want it to look like this:

```
en.foo.com/hello-world/
```

but both urls are the same page. Does anyone know if there is a plugin available for that or how i am able to do that. At the moment i am using qTranslate-X for translating everything else.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Qtranslate Slug](https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-slug/) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting up a wordpress multi site network, then using a plugin called 'transposh' to switch between translated pages.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

https://wordpress.org/plugins/transposh-translation-filter-for-wordpress/